# find a single specific place with google places api

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I was wondering if it is possible to find a specific place using the google places api.
I know the name of the place, the address or website url, and the coordinates.

I need this to get the ratings this place has.

Is this possible? If not, is it going to be?

Comment: do you want to know longitude and latitude with address?

Comment: no, i need to get the detailed info (especially its rating) of a place in google places. I already now the lat, long and address

Comment: check this link, may help you https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Comment: according to those docs i need a reference from a 'Place Search' first. I need to skip that step.

Comment: Google keep location details with reference and it is uniquely identifies a place. if want to use google api, then you have to follow google step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to do a `nearbysearch` with the `location` (lat,long), a small `radius`, and the `name` and `types` parameters to narrow it down.  If you are targeting a specific place, then you can just manually find it in the results and use its `reference` for a Details request in your solution.

If the target place can be dynamic, for example based on user input, then you might want to show the user the list of results and let them choose the correct one.  I don't think there's a way to guarantee that you will always get exactly the result you're looking for as, say, the first result in the list.  Experiment with different types of requests and parameters and try to get a sense for the behaviour of the responses to find what will work best for your solution.

Comment: this is what i was going to try for now. the small radius should help a lot with narrowing down to the place i'm looking for. Thanks for you help.